# Python: iterating files with time

Tags: python, date, time

I have a list of files that begin with a backwards date and time stamp:

```
201705150000_*
201705150005_*
201705150010_*
201705150015_*
```

I'm writing a script where the user will enter the start time and the duration of time required, e.g. 3hrs. The script will then query the specified files. The time step is every 5mins, so 12 files in an hour.

When it comes to the end of the hour, how can I stop the next file being 0060 and force it to 0100? I could manually list all possible time variations (eg. 0005, 0010, 0015 etc), but there must be a better way...

The user is entering these values as integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can iterate over the values, and replace each matching line:

```
  s = '201705150060_*'
  if s.find('60',10) > 0:  # checks 60 is a substring starting from location 10
      s = s.replace('60', '100')
  print(s)
```

As you can see, I have a string `s` that contains `60` in it's end. I verify that using `find` and then I replace that `60` with a `100`. You just need to do this in a loop, though I'm not sure if this is the *pythonic* way to do so (*I'm happy to hear better ways* :) )

Comment: Ok. But I'd have to specify `0060` as `60` may be elsewhere in the string. Same for `100`.

Comment: @DonkeyKong I don't understand the problem. You fear that this replace would change other "60" in the string?

Comment: Sorry, just realised `10` is the starting index. I understand now, thanks.

Comment: @DonkeyKong just note that _find_ method have begin and an end arguments you can set, so you can get very tight boundaries for your substring search :)

Answer (score 0):

Divide the last `4` digits of date-time field into hours and minutes, convert them in the true way and replace in the original string.

```
def fixIt(s):
    h, m = int(s[8:10]), int(s[10:])

    h += m // 60
    m =  m %  60

    return s[:8] + "{:02d}{:02d}".format(h, m)
```

`{:02d}` is a placeholder for `h` and `m` for the `format()` function and means to convert `h` and `m` to the strings with `2` characters for each (and with `0` in front of them - for 1-digit numbers).

Answer (score 0):

I find using datetime module always elegant for such purposes. for example code becomes generic for any duration.

using your list of times

```
file_times=["201705150000_","201705150005_","201705150010_","201705150015_"]
```

now parse this list with datetime to get a datetimelist

```
from datetime import datetime
datelist=[s.split('_')[0] for s in a]
datetimelist=[datetime.strptime(datei,"%Y%m%d%H%M") for datei in datelist]
```

the strptime and the format is the trick.

lets write a simple function to probe times inside this list given a user time in same string format and time duration.

```
def probetimes(datetimelist,stime,duration_in_seconds):
    starttime=datetime.strptime(stime,"%Y%m%d%H%M")
    real_starttime=min(datetimelist,key=lambda t: abs(t - newdt)) # bisect.left can be faster        
    startind=datetimelist.index(real_starttime)
    stoptime=starttime+timedelta(**{'seconds':duration_in_seconds})

    try:
        for current in datetimelist[startind:]:
            if current<stoptime:
                yield current.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%H')
    except StopIteration:
        pass #whatever you wants
```

here is output for one date and times for next one hour

```
print(list(probetime(datetimelist,'201705150012',3600)))
['201705150000', '201705150000']
```